# Algorithm works in parallel for a small network but not for a large network (OpenMP)

Tags: c, algorithm, openmp

I have an algorithm that runs the 2D Ising model and it works perfectly fine for small networks and for large networks in serial. When I refer to the lattice, I am referring to the size of the matrix of the system (which consequently tells the number of spins of the system). So far so good, but I needed to parallelize this algorithm, and I did it (using OpenMP). Everything seemed fine initially, I ran the algorithm with L = 2, 4, 8, 16 and everything was fine. The problem is that for small networks, parallelization does not show results and I know that, so I was going to do the definitive test using a matrix that makes the algorithm run in 3h (L = 528) and that's when the problem started: the algorithm didn't run . It doesn't show any errors but it doesn't run and I have no idea what it could be.

Please, help.

Comment: Start debugging to find out at which point in code the program gets stuck.

Comment: Start by making all loop variables local to the loop: `for (int j=whatever)`. Having `j` shared can be a big problem. Always declare your variables as local as possible.

Comment: Are you sure that algorithm is stuck rather than just taking a very very long time to calculate the result?

Comment: You realize that you're trying to do nested parallelism, right?

Comment: Also, you're sharing the random number generator state between all your threads, so you have quite a problem heer (you're defining `firstprivate` the pointer to a unique rng state so the pointers are private, but they all pointe to the same state).

Comment: Thanks for the answers folks! All helped a lot and the problem was solved!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your code stops with an exception, because of a stack overflow:

These are the relevant lines:

```
#define L 15
#define N  L*L 
...
int Rede[N][N];
...
#pragma omp parallel firstprivate(Rede)...
```

When `L=528`, `N` is `528*528=278784`, `Rede` requires `N*N*sizeof(int)` bytes which is about 290 Gbyte (not to mention that each thread creates a local copy of `Rede`).

UPDATE: Based on `inicia_malha` function most probably `Rede` should be declared as:

```
int Rede[L][L];
```

and you get rid of the overflow.

UPDATE2: As pointed out by @Gilles you have to create a random number generator for each thread. E.g:

```
#define MAX_THREADS 256
gsl_rng* r[MAX_THREADS];
for(int i=0;i<omp_get_max_threads();i++) {
   r[i]= gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_mt19937);
   gsl_rng_set(r[i], seed);
   //inicia a rede aleatóriamente
   inicia_malha(r[i], Rede);
}
```

and you try to use nested parallelism, but most probably nested parallelism is disabled in your OpenMP implementation, so as a result your `for` loop will be executed `omp_get_num_threads()` times. That is the reason why you have to divide your values by `number_T`, but it is an error.

Another comment you should use your variable at their minimum required scope, so putting it together your code should look something like this:

```
#define MAX_THREADS 256   
gsl_rng* r[MAX_THREADS];
for(int i=0;i<omp_get_max_threads();i++)
{
    r[i]= gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_mt19937);        //aloca espaço para o número aleatório de testagem
    gsl_rng_set(r[i], seed);
    //inicia a rede aleatóriamente
    inicia_malha(r[i], Rede);
}

//loop da temperatura
for(;T>=Tmin;T-=dT)
{
    //termalização
    equilibra(r[0], J, B, k, T, Rede);
    
    //I think it is correct and better if you set initial values here         
    double E_total=energia_total(J, B, Rede);
    double E2_total=E_total*E_total;
    double M_total=magnetizacao_total(Rede);
    double M2_total=M_total*M_total;
    double Mabs_total=abs(M_total);

    #pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(Msteps, J, B, k, T,r) \
    firstprivate(Rede) reduction(+: E_total, E2_total, M_total, M2_total, Mabs_total)      
    //loop do Monte Carlo
    for(unsigned int i=1;i<=Msteps;i++){
        int  pos[2], dE=0;
        int thread_num=omp_get_thread_num();
        double E=0, M=0;
        //loop de Metropolis
        for(unsigned int j=1;j<=N;j++){
            escolhe_pos(pos, r[thread_num]);                
            if(testa_flip(pos, &dE, r[thread_num], J, B, k, T, Rede)){
                //ajusta os observáveis
                E+=2*dE;
                M+=2*Rede[pos[0]][pos[1]];
            }
        }            
        //soma dos observavéis
        E_total+=E;
        E2_total+= E*E;
        M_total+=M;
        M2_total+= M*M;
        Mabs_total+=abs(M);
    }
    //..... more code here
}
```

Comment: `528*528*sizeof(int)` is more like 1MB, which by today's standard isn't much... It might require enlarging slightly the stack size and/or set `OMP_STACKSIZE` to a larger-than-default value. But that shouldn't be much of a showstopper.

Comment: @Gilles  `N=L*L=278784`, so N*N=77,720,518,656

Comment: Thanks for the answers folks! All helped a lot and the problem was solved!!!